# What could a hypothetically long transparent and super strong nano fiber be made of?

Tags: materials

Hoping to get a couple ideas for the following context. Looking at building a planetary dome using transparent nano fibers and the only hypothetical materials that come to mind is some diamond/graphene/silica type polymer. Looking to see if anyone knows of any other way to approach the description with a semi-plausible rationale that wouldn't make a material scientist say it would 100% be impossible. 99% impossible is good enough for me :)

Comment: Welcome! Can you describe your "planetary dome" a bit more?  Does this envelop the planet, sit on its surface, etc? What's its approximate size or scale?

Comment: Hey! It sits on the surface but I'm thinking of something that could act as a transparent high tensile very durable almost nano thread type material.

Comment: For the record, I'm an electrical engineer and, despite not being a rocket scientist, I can often point out what's factually wrong about the so-called "realistic" books and movies out there. Don't worry too much about details like this. Larry Niven is famous for sitting at a convention while MIT students marched the halls chanting "The Ringworld is Unstable!" Rather than being embarrassed by it, he wrote a second *Ringworld* book, explained the solution, and raked in the cash. Write a great story, don't sweat such small worldbuilding details.

Comment: Would you absolutely need it to be transparent, or would the Truman show solution with a solid dome with coloured light on the inside be enough?

Comment: You know that transparent materials have flat surfaces for a reason? Make glass or plastics into a curved fibre and at human scales you've got translucent instead. See [refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction) for detailed explanation. In light of that, what are you asking? Perhaps see JHB's comment for guidance as to the relative importance of correct-tech and story.

Comment: Thanks everyone and appreciate the insight JBH.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not going to answer this directly - because if I did, I'd probably VTC it as brainstorming. But I will answer indirectly, from one of my favourite Universes - Warhammer 40K:

Adamantium: A Virtually indestructible Metal, capable of withstanding attacks from most weaponary.

Plasteel: a type of advanced synthetic material that has the consistency of plastic but the tensile strength of a steel alloy

Ceramite: A type of Heat and shock resistant Ceramic-like material, often used in conjunction with plasteel to make a composite armor that is highly resistant common weaponary.

Ferrocrete: synthetic compound it is composed of a mix of metallic alloys, ceramic polymers and stone.
It has high density and ability to stand for thousands of standard years in a wide variety of climates and planetary environments once it sets.

**If you need a Futuristic material - simply give it a name, describe it's properties and be done with it**

For added points, add in some common other words that *hint* at what it *could* be made of, but with enough plausible deniability to get you your 1% believability.

Comment: Not in-universe (probably), but don't forget Handwavium!

Comment: My favorite is how "unobtanium" somehow made it into the final script of Avatar.

Comment: On the "added points", if your characters aren't material scientists, they probably don't know; if they are material scientists, do the same trick but with the category of material and the manufacturing process. 'My God, Doctor, this stuff is incredible. It has the consistency of plastic but the tensile strength of a steel alloy. It seems to be be a Roddenberry-Shatner synthetic, but to make it this long without weaving strands together, they must have solved the Hammil problem with Lucas accretion."

Comment: Great answers all around and thanks for the chuckles. :)

Answer (score 3):

In real life scientists are looking at still experimental but clearly possible ways to combine graphene with optical fiber, both by combining the graphene with silica as a composite and by getting the graphene to go in to a glassy state they call it, which they want to use as sensors, etc because you can also make 2D optical things, so those are things people are just starting to think of now but it is still experimental for the most part.

So I was thinking an idea is maybe the dome is held together in part with fiber optic graphene cabling so that the cables holding things together are functional as data transfer cables.  You can also direct sunlight through them and be able to point or direct sunlight, people do this now to make skylights where they need to bend the direction of the light to come in the house, so it has that ability also.  The glassy sheets of graphene can make sensors also like I mentioned, so you could have sensor panels on the dome used as surveillance systems or used to monitor something, and the data could be sent back through the cables.

So that is maybe more detailed scenario than you are asking but the silica-graphene material may be a good one because you can think of a lot of functional reasons why it is there.

I just had a thought also that it would not be impossible to make a dome that was kind of invisible with that stuff also, using the fiber optics to also pass light through so it would make a really strong but transparent barrier that could send data and light around.

Comment: I'm glad you brought this up because I was legitimately thinking of a graphene diamond silica nano polymer, but didn't think about it being able to transfer light and therefore info in the way you suggested. Genius